# How to search an array of elements in a field in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array like below

```
arr = [123,176]
```

I have 2 records as

```
{ 
    '_id':'123',
    'geo':'-87.988'
},
{
   '_id':'198',
   'geo':'-98.822.
}
```

I wrote the query as

```
arr = [123,192]

MyTable.find(_id:{$in: arr}).function(err,values){
  console.log(err);
}
```

> Error: Cast to ObectId failed for value '123'.

How do I solve this?

Comment: try arr = ["123","192"]

Comment: @MMR I have implemented the same and does not found any error as mentioned by you and yes as suggested by #Fluffy as your records are stored in string so you need search it as a string but either way It is not giving any error

Comment: If you are still getting error update your question with little more details.

Comment: Thanks all...its my typo error in my code.Any how thanks.

Comment: Hello. can you show your mongoose schema code?